# Sails.js put models, services etc in subfolders

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

When creating a new api entity, for example a  service, model or controller, Sails will automatically create the file in the associated folder.

That's fine until your project grows. To tidy things up a little I tried grouping certain entities into folders. However, when doing this, sails no longer injects those entities correctly.

Is there any way of grouping certain entities in subfolders and still have sails inject those correctly into my controllers / other places?

Comment: I think it could only work if you edited the SailS source files... Maybe a fork?

Comment: @ paulogdm That doesn't sound like a good idea, considering I want to maintain the ability to upgrade sails. Sure a fork might work but it's still a lot of effort. I find it surprising that no one else was requesting this feature, I don't see how you can manage larger scale projects otherwise. Sails calls itself enterprise-grade after all.

Comment: In our project we group models and controllers in subfolders, but we never use any "automatics" that sails provides from the console. We do it manually. Frankly, I am not sure if or when these things would be supported.